# What are the User Agents of some old browsers?

Tags: browser, user-agent

I want to serve mobile content for browsers older than IE7. All I could find on Google was that the User Agent for IE 6 is "MSIE 6". What about IE 5 and below?  And Netscape and early versions of FF and Opera?

Comment: All those browsers are effectively extinct. IE6 is really the only one still encountered on a semi-regular basis, and most easily handled with a [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This site has the user agent strings for most browsers (old versions and new versions).
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Internet Explorer:
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Internet+Explorer

Firefox:
http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Firefox

Opera: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Opera

Comment: As the site seems to be down now, here's an Archive.org link:
http://web.archive.org/web/20130327103816/http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Answer (score 0):

[user-agents.org](http://www.user-agents.org/) has a pretty comprehensive list of user agents including browsers, spiders, robots and crawlers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve the same content but styled differently a better approach is CSS media queries.

To support really old browsers from microsoft conditional comments are easy to implement as well.

Any older than that I would strongly recommend not doing anything for. On the contrary suggest to those users to upgrade to newer browsers.

You can still find user agent strings on sites like http://www.user-agents.org/

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty exhaustive list. - [Browser ID Strings (aka User Agent ID)](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/browser_ids.htm)